# Marshalling data in out parameters and ref

Tags: c#

On C# side I have code like

```
[DllImport("dppClientModule.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern UInt32 dppModuleDeinit(
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    dppErrorInfo_t pErrInfo);
```

But it is called like

```
  dppErrorInfo_t ei = new dppErrorInfo_t();
  UInt32 result = dppModuleDeinit(ei);
```

My first question is: Isn't in above line a `ref` keyword missing with `ei`?

Also there is another wrapper function like:

```
private void Test(ref dppErrorInfo_t x)
{
    UInt32 result = dppModuleDeinit(x);    
}
```

My second question is: Will the **caller** of `Test` observe change in `x` variable? (assuming `dppModuleDeinit` does indeed change the original variable)

*Note: Because normally if `dppModuleDeinit` required `ref` parameter you would additionally have to put `ref` before `x` when passing to `dppModuleDeinit` function otherwise that would not work.*

PS Here is how that function looks on C++

```
dppFUNC(HRESULT) dppModuleDeinit( 
    dppErrorInfo_t  *pErrInfo) ; // Error info
```

Comment: There are three options : 1) out : If the memory is being declared in side method.  2) ref : if memory is being declared in main routine, values being changed in method, and changes need to be seen by calling method. 3) Nothing : if memory is being declared in main routine and values are being passed to method, and main routine does not need too see any changes made by method.

Comment: @jdweng: I really don't understand your comment, and can't see how it answers the question

Comment: You did not declare the pErrInfo argument with the ref keyword.  Maybe that was wrong, likely it was, there isn't any point in letting us guess about that when you can post the C declaration of the function.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am not sure I understood your comment but I have updated the question - please see

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually I think compiler doesn't even let me put ref or out with `ei` parameter

Comment: It is passed by reference, as expected.  You *must* use the `ref` keyword in your DllImport declaration if you declared dppErrorInfo_t as a struct.  If you declared it as a class then you don't.

Comment: @HansPassant: In C# dppErrorInfo_t  is class. What about my second question?

Comment: If it is a class then there is no point at all in using `ref` in your Test method.

Comment: @HansPassant: And caller of Test will observe change in x?? Because normally you know if you don't pass by reference class objects and inside function just do simple reassignment e.g. x=newObj caller will not see this. Isn't it?

Comment: It is fine, you just don't understand well enough how ref works.  It is only required when Test creates a new instance of the class.  It doesn't, x does not change at all.  Only the members of x change.

Comment: @HansPassant: I understand believe me. I mean if I don't use ref with argument for Test and inside Test I just to `x = newObj`. Caller will not see this change right? (even if x is class object).

Comment: That's nonsensical code.  If you use x = new dppErrorInfo_t() then, yes, you need ref to let the caller see the new object you created.

Comment: @HansPassant: If `dppModuleDeinit`  had requirement for its argument to be ref, then you would have to additionally use ref on `x` inside Test when passing to `dppModuleDeinit`, isn't it? Why not here?

Comment: dppErrorInfo_t is declared as a struct inside the C code, that requires pErrInfo to be a pointer so changes to the struct are visible to the caller.  If you also declare it as a struct in your C# code then you'll be a lot less confused and you'll use ref consistently.  Object references in C# are pointers under the hood.

Comment: @HansPassant: I know but like I said take following example that `dppModuleDeinit` requires ref for parameter. Now in this case we would be forced to use ref on `x` also in Test method when passing to `dppModuleDeinit` right? But as in the question you mean still caller of `Test` will see change on x?

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be fine as you defined multiple type [In, Out, ref] with parameter.
2. for all LOB, .NET internally pass these parameters as ref. So caller of Test must observe the changes.

Comment: what do you mean with LOB?

Comment: LOB --> large objects on heap (large object blocks)